# Odoo Make to Order Configuration for all products

Tags: odoo

I am working on Odoo 8.0 I have our Sales and Ordering system configured with 5473 products.  I have also configured our suppliers and they are linked to the appropriate products.  I have verified the suppliers have the address field entered and we are almost ready to go.

However to enable automatic procurement for RFQ (Request For Quotation) I have found out that on any product under the procurement tab there are route_ids.  One is Buy and one is Make to Order.  I have been told in order for RFQ's to be kicked off automatically that the Buy and Make to Order checkboxes need to be enabled.

I have went through the models, fields and database and cannot seem to find the table where these to checkboxes are set.  Can anyone help me out with which table I can dump and modify then reimport to automatically set both checkbox fields?

Answer (score 0):

To find out stuff like this quickly, Odoo has a "trick": if you click in the upper right on your username and "About Odoo", you can click "Activate Developer Mode". Now, when you go to the view of a product, click "Edit", and hover over a field label, it will show information about the field.

In this case, hovering over "Routes" tells us that this is a "many2many" field called "route_ids", bringing the object "product.product" in relation with "stock_location_route".

Usually the corresponding database table would be called something like "stock_location_route_product_rel", but in this case we are not that lucky. However the [Odoo source code (addons/stock/product.py)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/stock/product.py#L427) gives us the definition of this relation:

```
'route_ids': fields.many2many('stock.location.route', 'stock_route_product', 'product_id', 'route_id', 'Routes', domain="[('product_selectable', '=', True)]",
                                help="Depending on the modules installed, this will allow you to define the route of the product: whether it will be bought, manufactured, MTO/MTS,..."),
```

Which tells us that the table name is "stock_route_product".

The following query will give you the checkboxes set on a certain subset of products,

```
select pt.name, slr.name
from stock_route_product srp
inner join product_template pt on srp.product_id = pt.id
inner join stock_location_route slr on srp.route_id = slr.id
where pt.name like '%keyword%'
and slr.name in ('Make To Order', 'Buy');
```

Or for all products,

```
select pt.name, slr.name
from stock_route_product srp
inner join product_template pt on srp.product_id = pt.id
inner join stock_location_route slr on srp.route_id = slr.id
where slr.name in ('Make To Order', 'Buy');
```

Actually, following query is even more insightful, here you will see the missing checks displayed as NULL,

```
select pt_id, slr_id, srp.route_id, srp.product_id
from (
  select pt.id as pt_id, slr.id as slr_id
  from stock_location_route slr, product_template pt
  where slr.name in ('Make To Order', 'Buy')
) q
left join stock_route_product srp 
  on srp.route_id = q.slr_id 
  and srp.product_id = q.pt_id
```

Now then this is the list of missing records you need to insert in stock_route_product (using INSERT or import/export):

```
select pt_id, slr_id
from (
  select pt.id as pt_id, slr.id as slr_id
  from stock_location_route slr, product_template pt
  where slr.name in ('Make To Order', 'Buy')
) q
left join stock_route_product srp
  on srp.route_id = q.slr_id
  and srp.product_id = q.pt_id
where srp.route_id is null
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps so much!  Can you tell me rather then using the line where pt.name like '%keyword%'
and slr.name in ('Make To Order', 'Buy'); if it can be modified for all products?

Comment: Can you help me with modifying this query for all products?                               where pt.name like '%keyword%'  .

Comment: The provided code was given as an answer to a question about how to automatically make two check boxes (make to order and buy) automatically set for each product.  Here is the link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611721/odoo-make-to-order-configuration-for-all-products/31628614#31628614   .   In answer to where is the upsert  I am not sure at the moment.   I am in need of some help.

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer to include the query that should be run to see all products.

Comment: I also included a query that shows the records to be inserted for the missing checkboxes. In fact an UPSERT is not necessary, just an INSERT.

Comment: I have used the queries above and buy is chosen on all the products as before.  However the query makes no change to the make to order checkbox.  Across products.

Comment: If it helps it looks like the correct number in the route_id field of the stock_route_product is the number 1 when buy and make to order are chosen.