# Update Route in Odoo 12

Tags: odoo

How can I update the product `Route_ids` routes in Odoo 12 with a query?

The selection of products I can do with the answer from this link.
[Odoo Make to Order Configuration for all products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611721/odoo-make-to-order-configuration-for-all-products)

Thanks
Maybe with these :

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'write', [[id], {'route_ids': [(1, a, b)]}])
```

What is a and b? I think that 1 it's for the update, is right?

I think that the answer is that but i'm not sure  :

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'write', [[id], {'route_ids': [(1, 915, 17)]}])
```

`1` is for the update, `915` is the product id, and `17` is the `route_id`.

The question is how can I do a list of products to update the routes?
According with the answer of CZoellner  maybe is

models.execute_kw(db, uid, pw, 'product.template',
'write', [[17], {'route_ids': [(6, 0, [915,916])]}])

It's Right?

Ok Ive do :

```
import sys
import xmlrpclib
import ssl

url = "http://localhost:8069"
db = "*******"
username = "*******"
pw = "*******"

gcontext = ssl._create_unverified_context()

# Get the uid

    sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(
        "http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common", context=gcontext)

    uid = sock_common.login(db, username, pw)
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object", context=gcontext)
    
    models.execute_kw(
        db, uid, pw, "product.template", "write", [[916], {"route_ids": [(6, 0, [17])]}]
    )
```

It thasn't work, where is my mistake?

It's these code work with odoo 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of answers about how the magic triplets for many2many fields in Odoo have to be used already. My advice for this basic question: look into the docstring of `BaseModel.write()` because the answer to that is there for ages.

But for your special question: If you want to set a product route to only one route, just use the "override" triplet `(6, 0, <list_of_ids_to_set>)`. If you just want to add another route to all current set routes use the "add" triplet `(4, <id_of_route_to_add>, 0)` (you could leave the 0 at the end).

So if your Make2order route is for example ID 3:

```py
models.execute_kw(db, uid, pw, 'product.template',
    'write', [[template_id], {'route_ids': [(6, 0, [3])]}])
```

or

```py
models.execute_kw(db, uid, pw, 'product.template',
    'write', [[template_id], {'route_ids': [(4, 3,)]}])
```

Comment: So with these i'll overrride  a list of products_id 915 and 916 , it's right?

models.execute_kw(db, uid, pw, 'product.template',
    'write', [[template_id], {'route_ids': [(6, 0, [915,916])]}])

And How can i put route_id 17 , to these products? 

Thanks

Comment: No the triplets will get the route IDs. Product IDs belong to where i wrote template_id. Odoo is expecting 2 method parameters for method `write`, which will be a list of IDs to write/update and a python dictionary with field names as key and there values to write.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have solved with Mass edit Module , I know it would be better to do what you say CZoellner. Thanks a lot.